# Expectation of Log Likelihood Function with given parameters Proof

Tags: expected-value, aic, kullback-leibler, likelihood

I have been looking for AICc value derivation employing Kullback-Leibler distance but as a result of my search I got stuck with expectation of loglikelihood. In the [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjc7I7M5aPkAhVXSBUIHdoYARoQFjABegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyweb.uiowa.edu%2Fcavaaugh%2Fdoc%2Fpub%2Faicaicc.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0jFN7JETW9Z51TPug_F-_T) loglikelihood is given as $InL(\theta|Y_n) = \frac{-n} {2}In 2\pi - \frac {n} {2}In\sigma^2 - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2}(y-X\beta)^{'}(y-X\beta)$ where the candidate model is $y=X\beta + e$ whereas e is $N(0,\sigma^2I)$ 
Thus, according to given log likelihood function, in equation 2.19, 2.20, 2.21 it is written successively as: 
$E_0(-2InL(\theta_0|Y_n)) = nIn\sigma_0^2 + n(1+In2\pi)$
$E_0(-2InL(\hat\theta_n|Y_n)) = E_0(nIn\hat\sigma_n^2) + n(1+In2\pi)$
$E_0(-2InL(\theta|Y_n))|_{\theta=\hat\theta_n} = nIn\hat\sigma_n^2 + n\frac {\sigma_0^2} {\hat\sigma_n^2} + \frac 1 {\hat\sigma_n^2} (\hat\beta_n-\beta_0)^{'}(X^{'}X)(\hat\beta_n-\beta_0) +nIn2\pi$

But I can not derive the listed equations (2.19, 2.20, 2.21) for a given loglikehood function. Could you help me about that?